# Execute background program in bash without job control

Tags: bash, job-control

I often execute GUI programs, such as firefox and evince from shell. If I type "firefox &", firefox is considered as a bash job, so "fg" will bring it to foreground and "hang" the shell. This becomes annoying when I have some background jobs such as vim already running.

What I want is to launch firefox and dis-associate it with bash. Consider the following ideal case with my imaginary runbg:

```
$ vim foo.tex
ctrl+z and vim is job 1
$ pdflatex foo
$ runbg evince foo.pdf
evince runs in background and I get me bash prompt back
$ fg
vim goes foreground
```

Is there any way to do this using existing program? If not, I will write my own runbg.

Comment: `nohup` and `disown` are not what you're after?

Comment: Note that you can specify the job that you want to move to the foreground i.e. `fg %1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
( firefox & )
```

This seems to keep it out of the jobs table, and `fg` can't see it at all.

Comment: It works. clever idea.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
bash$ firefox &
bash$ disown
```

Bash has now forgotten about the background job you just created.

Comment: After using it for sometime, I couldn't get used to it. The problem is I have to specify the job number. disown with no argument doesn't detach the previous background job, but the "current job", which I found strangely defined.

Comment: I believe the most-recently backgrounded job is always the current job, unless you change the current job before you type `disown`.

Comment: Hi Fran, try this. 1. vim foo; 2. gedit bar &; 3. disown; 4. fg. Step 3 disowns vim and step 4 brings gedit to foreground. After reading bash manual, I still don't know why bash considers vim as the current job in step 3.